# registrar en archivo de texto tiempo trancurrido entre presion a dos botones. Codigo no funciona

Tags: vb.net, vb

Cuando el usuario da click en un botón ese botón se oculta y otros dos aparecen. Cuando aparecen el usuario debe elegir entre cualquiera de esos dos, al dar click en alguno de ellos aparece una imagen durante 3 segundos y se reinicia (vuelve a ocultarse la imagen, y los últimos dos botones).
Quiero registrar el tiempo entre la aparición los dos botones y cuando el usuario de click en cualquiera de ellos.
Cree este código para medir el tiempo

```
 Public Inicio_eleccion As Integer '
    Function Iniciar_ch() '
        Inicio_eleccion = Environment.TickCount '
        Return Inicio_eleccion
    End Function
    Public Duracion_ch As Integer '
    Function Total_desicion() '
        Duracion_ch = Environment.TickCount '
        Return (Duracion_ch - Inicio_eleccion)
    End Function
```

Hice tambien la subrutina del cambio en el que inicio el conteo del tiempo cuando se da click al boton

```
 Private Sub Boton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Boton1.Click
        cambio()
       

    End Sub

    Sub cambio()
        Iniciar_tiempo()
        Boton2.Enabled = True
        Boton2.Visible = True
        Boton3.Visible = True
        Boton3.Enabled = True
        Boton1.Visible = False



    End Sub
```

Y lo que sucede al dar click en los otros botones

```
 Private Sub Boton2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Boton2.Click

        Reforzar()


    End Sub

    Private Sub Boton3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Boton3.Click

        Reforzar()



    End Sub
    Sub Reforzar()

        'Iniciar_Ref()

        Boton1.Visible = False
        Boton2.Visible = False
        Boton3.Visible = False
        Tom.Visible = True
        Do
            If Duración_Ref() > 3000 Then Exit Do
            My.Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        Tom.Visible = False
        Boton1.Visible = True
        Boton2.Visible = False
        Boton3.Visible = False
        Total_desicion()
        TxT.WriteLine( Duración de la elección:" & Duracion_ch)-----*
        Cerrartxt()
        Me.Close()





    End Sub
```

Quiero registrar el tiempo en un archivo de texto que ya cree pero al correr el programa marca error donde está el asterisco. Les agradecería muchisimo si me ayudaran a encontrar el error.

Answer (score 0):

Las Funciones Necesitan Especificar el Delegado y los Parámetros, y a las Variables Asignar-les un Valor por defecto...

Así Debes Escribir las Funciones ( Public o Private ) y Asignar los Valores de Retorno...

```
Public Inicio_eleccion As Integer = 0 '
Public Function Iniciar_ch() As Integer '
    Inicio_eleccion = Environment.TickCount '
    Return Inicio_eleccion
End Function

Public Duracion_ch As Integer = 0 '
Public Function Total_desicion() As Integer '
    Duracion_ch = Environment.TickCount '
    Return (Duracion_ch - Inicio_eleccion)
End Function
```

También tienes errores en las subrutinas de el tercer ejemplo.

TxT.WriteLine( "Duración de la elección: " & Duracion_ch ) ' Línea de error